Analytical proof of the existence of excited states for the Schrödinger-Newton equation
I have learned about the Schrödinger-Newton equation and from what I understand we know quite  a bit both numerically and analytically about the existence of a ground state for a spherically symmetric wavefunction. But do we know analytically if there are any  stable excited states?
